# Implementing own Client ID shows discrepancies compared to GA Client ID

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I want to implement my own Test-Client ID with the following Skript:

```
<script>
(function(){

    var cookie = readCookie("customClientID"); 
    var storage = window.localStorage; 
    var storageClientID = storage.getItem("customClientID""); 
    var userID = userId(); 
    var agent = window.navigator.userAgent; 

    if(!cookie && !storageClientID){
        createCookie("customClientID"", userID, 2);
        storage.setItem("customClientID"", readCookie("customClientID"")); 
    }else if(cookie && !storageClientID){
        storage.setItem("customClientID"", readCookie("customClientID""));
    }else if(!cookie && storageClientID){
        createCookie("customClientID"", storageUserId, 2);
    }else{}

    //Create UUID
    function userId() {
        try{
            return new Date().getTime() + '.' + Math.random().toString(36).substring(5) + '.' + hash(agent);
        }catch(e){}
    }

     //Hash Function
    function hash(str){
        try{
            var hash = 0;
            for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
                var charI = str.charCodeAt(i);
                hash = ((hash<<5)-hash)+charI;
                hash = hash & hash; // Convert to 32bit integer
                }   
                hash = hash & hash;
                hash = hash.toString().replace("-", "");
            return hash; 
    }catch(e){}
    }

    //Read Cookie https://www.quirksmode.org/
    function readCookie(name) {
        try{
            var nameEQ = name + "=";
            var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
            for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
                var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
                if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
            }
            return null;
        }catch(e){}
    }

    //Create Cookie https://www.quirksmode.org/
    function createCookie(name,value,days) {
        try{
            if (days) {
                var date = new Date();
                date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
                var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
            }else var expires = "";
                document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
        }catch(e){}
    }
})();
```

The if block checks if the cookie is set and the cookie value also appears in the local storage. If the cookie is not found a new cookie is set with a value generated function userId().

To get the customClientID value out of the cookie I use the internal GTM First Party Cookie variable. The custom HTML tag with the script above fires on All Pages - Pageview.

Finally I've set a Custom Dimension (User Scope) with the First Party Cookie variable (customClientID) value in each tag.

When I compare the Users Metric of the original GA ClientID I get 1 User for each ClientID which is correct. However, if I compare the customClientID in a custom report with the same date range e.g. one day I get a lot of Users with the same customClientID. There are also less Users in sum compared to the original ClientID.

We have a high traffic website so my first assumption is that the script is maybe to slow to handle a lot of users entering and browsing at the same time. Many users would get the same customClientID.

Second assumption is that the custom dimension should only set within the page view tag.

Hope you understand my issue and many thanks in advance!

PS: I posted it here https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/tag-manager/syet129zIqI;context-place=forum/tag-manager as well.

Best, 
Anton

Comment: "script is maybe to slow to handle a lot of users entering" - Javascript is run on the client, so it always deals with a single user.

Comment: Thanks @EikePierstorff for the hint.